# Find as well as update in 4 level array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have to find as well as update in 4 level array in MongoDB, like my department Page is an array having multiple departments, and my all departments having multiple divisions and all divisions having multiple designations, so I have to find only those array of designations which fulfill the condition and also have to update with push, pull and set

*Example structure*

```
{
    "_id": "5649bb56db5648617ed36556",
    "departmentPage": {
        "departmentPageInfo": {
            "active": "1"
        },
        "departments": [
            {
                "_id": "56501d09cbb8a41d27c1c0e4",
                "active": 1,
                "divisions": [
                    {
                        "_id": "56501d69cbb8a49319c1c0e4",
                        "active": 1,
                        "departmentId": "56501d09cbb8a41d27c1c0e4",
                        "designations": [

                        ],
                        "instanceNo": 1,
                        "order": 1,
                        "title": "Php Development Recruitment"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "565078edcbb8a44546c1c0e4",
                        "active": 1,
                        "departmentId": "56501d09cbb8a41d27c1c0e4",
                        "designations": [
                            {
                                "_id": "56507944cbb8a44546c1c0e5",
                                "active": 1,
                                "departmentId": "56501d09cbb8a41d27c1c0e4",
                                "divisionId": "565078edcbb8a44546c1c0e4",
                                "instanceNo": 1,
                                "order": "1",
                                "title": "Senior php developer"
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "5650795ccbb8a4b851c1c0e4",
                                "active": 1,
                                "departmentId": "56501d09cbb8a41d27c1c0e4",
                                "divisionId": "565078edcbb8a44546c1c0e4",
                                "instanceNo": 3,
                                "order": "1",
                                "title": "Junior php developer"
                            }
                        ],
                        "instanceNo": 2,
                        "order": "1",
                        "title": "Php Development "
                    }
                ],
                "instanceNo": 1,
                "order": 1,
                "title": "Information Technology (IT)"
            },
            {
                "_id": "56501d33cbb8a41f14c1c0e5",
                "active": 1,
                "divisions": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5652c228cbb8a4e152bfeb99",
                        "active": 1,
                        "departmentId": "56501d33cbb8a41f14c1c0e5",
                        "designations": [
                            {
                                "_id": "565305e7cbb8a4ef56bfeb9a",
                                "instanceNo": 1,
                                "departmentId": "56501d33cbb8a41f14c1c0e5",
                                "divisionId": "5652c228cbb8a4e152bfeb99",
                                "title": "Cashier",
                                "active": 1,
                                "order": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "5653edaacbb8a4df74bfeb99",
                                "instanceNo": 2,
                                "departmentId": "56501d33cbb8a41f14c1c0e5",
                                "divisionId": "5652c228cbb8a4e152bfeb99",
                                "title": "Cash Collection Agent",
                                "active": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
]
}
}
```

This is what i tried:

```
db.department.aggregate([
  {$unwind : '$departmentPage.departments.divisions.designations'}, 
  {$match :     
     {'departmentPage.departments.divisions.designations._id':ObjectId("")} 
  }
])
```

It gives 0 result, it is working till department, but after that it's giving 0 result

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please tell us what you have tried or read. If you have received and error please tell us what it is.

Comment: I am trying to get the data from db using $unwind (aggregation) with $match, it is working fine till 2 level of array but not working with 4 level of array.

Comment: Great! Please edit the question and show your aggregation code.

Comment: here is my query...       
db.department.aggregate({$unwind : '$departmentPage.departments.divisions.designations'},
{$match : {'departmentPage.departments.divisions.designations._id':ObjectId("56501d09cbb8a41d27c1c0e4")}})      

but it gives 0 result,  it is working till department, but after that it's giving 0 result